# Game theory and video games

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, game-theory

A friend of mine is planning to create an educational video on the theme of Game theory.

His teaching strategy is to introduce the subject via video games.

For example, he told me that the game " Fortnite" has, as drawback, to lead to some sort of " Nash Equilibrium" ( in which gamers are induced to protect themselves around walls, and to adopt a " wait and see" attitude, any initiative having costs greater than possiblle gains).

I do not want to claim that my friend's claim is correct ( for I have absolutely no understanding , either of game theory or of video games).

My question is simply :

(1) could video games provide a good illustration of game theoretical concepts

(2) are there references on this possible link between the two fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Games, and indeed video games, can demonstrate game theory principles, and I am sure a complex game like *Fortnite* has many examples. In general, game designers use many other principles to craft experiences and math is not central in their thinking. (When it is, a lot of the math goes towards balancing risk and reward, and this is more like inverse insurance math than game theory.)

2) A book on game design I highly recommend is *[Rules of Play](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262240459)*. It has a chapter on game theory and how it is used in games. It will also give you a nice perspective of how important it is compared to other topics such as simulation, emergence, and probability.